# Pythonic way to check if comparison value is a value or function then compare

Tags: python

I need to check a value against something else, `f`, that is either just a value or it is something callable that returns a value based on the value of another variable `p`.  I am looking for a more Pythonic way than I have written below to do this, if one exists:

```
p = 5  # Some value that is available in the code

def check_val(x):
    if callable(x):
        return x(p)
    else:
        return x

#Either/or
f = 1
f = lambda a: 1.5*a

if 2 < check_val(f):
    print("no good")
```

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but you could try posting this to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to see if anyone else has any inspiration.

Comment: Write two different functions, `check_value` and `check_predicate_against_p`.

Comment: I would suggest simply trying to call `x(p)` and catching the `TypeError` that gets raised if `x` is not callable, but that can't distinguish between an uncallable `x` and the situation where the call to `x(p)` itself raises an uncaught `TypeError`.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, but you should at least try to assign values with similar interfaces to a given variable. Functions (and other callables) have little in common with non-callable values.

Comment: You don't say how `f` would be set, but passing `lambda _: x` would let `check_val` treat its argument as a function unconditionally, while still getting a result of `x` back.

Answer (score -1):

Since your control flow depends on object type, you should be able to find a relevant type class in the `types` module.

```py
import types # see https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html

p = 5  # Some value that is available in the code

def check_val(x, p):
    if isinstance(x, (types.FunctionType, types.LambdaType):
        return x(p)
    else:
        return x

#Either/or
f = 1
f = lambda a: 1.5*a

if 2 < check_val(f, p):
    print("no good")
```

Comment: There are other callables besides `FunctionType` and `LambdaType`.

Comment: You are correct. The example used a lambda. If my answer is correct but incomplete you can edit it or suggest an edit. But is it wrong?